# AngularJS 1.6 + Webpack dev server - "Module 'app' is not available!"

Tags: angularjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to set up a simple AngularJS app with webpack dev server, but I can't get angular to work. HTML is being served up fine. I'm getting the errors

- "Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it..."
- "Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
  Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it."

webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {

entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/app.js'),

devtool: 'source-map',
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        title: 'Development'
    })
],

output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '.')
},

plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: 'index.html'
    }),
]
};
```

app.js

```
import angular from 'angular';
require ('./MainController.js');

console.log('hello world')

angular
  .module('app', []);
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>AngularJS SPA</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div>hello</div>
  <div ng-controller="MainController as main"> 
    {{ main.name }}
    <div ng-repeat="result in main.searchResults">{{ result }}</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

First time with webpack dev server and I've been googling for a while. Thanks

Comment: I believe you're missing `ng-app` in your `index.html`

Comment: It's right on line 2

Comment: show MainController.js -> i guess you use there your module before it is created

Comment: was this issue solved? if so how?

Comment: @killer_manatee Did you ever resolve this? If so, it would be very useful if you added an answer.